# TouchableWithoutFeedback not able to detect onPress when absoulte view is present in it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

When an absolute View is places inside an TouchableWithoutFeedback component onPress is not detected of the TouchableWithoutFeedback Component.

```
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          onPress={this.onPreddbackDrop}>
          <Animated.View
            importantForAccessibility="no"
            style={[styles.absolute, {opacity: this.state.backdropOpacity}]}>
            <View
              style={[
                styles.absolute,
                {
                  backgroundColor: this.props.backdropColor,
                  opacity: this.props.backdropOpacity,
                }
              ]}
            />
            {this.props.backdropContent || []}
          </Animated.View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

.........................